# Clicking "I'm done" without any action on an accepted answer fails the audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I was recently presented with [this audit](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/135891) of an accepted answer that looked fine to me. Without any action on my side, the "I'm done" button was available. I assumed this was due to the answer being accepted (I haven't encountered this situation before) and I considered it worth clicking.

> Fail.

So there are basically two bugs here:

- the "I'm done" button shouldn't have been available since I didn't do anything
- Since I didn't downvote, flag or comment, the audit shouldn't have failed

Comment: I never reviewed much (if anything), but all the reported problems with audits don't make me eager to try such seemingly demotivating endeavour.

Comment: @Arjan Nah, it's a relatively rare occurence, but even a rare bug should be fixed if easily possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I fixed the "`I'm Done` button being enabled w/o action" part thanks to [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207414/im-done-button-available-without-action).

So now in a First Post audit, you *have* to do either `No Action` or `Skip`. And since any of the actions on the post (edit, comment, ...) that would enable the `I'm Done` button  also complete the audit, you now shouldn't even have a chance to click it.

The fix will be available in build rev `2013.11.15.1647` on meta and `2013.11.15.1158` on sites