# "I'm Done" button available without action

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, review-abuse

I've started to do some reviews this week. Since then I observed that sometimes without doing anything the **I'm Done** button was available. I had this bug quite regularly, maybe in every second audit.

If this occurs it is quite obvious that an audit is occurring and one should do **anything**. Either upvoting for good posts or flagging/downvoting for bad contributions. Clicking **I'm Done** fails the audit.

See for example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This only happens on audit posts, and not on actual reviews?

Comment: At least this is what I belief. Several times I noticed it and flagged or upvoted which revealed the audit.

Comment: I just got an audit in the First Post queue, and the "I'm Done" button was grayed out like normal. But, the more obvious "this is an audit" UI hint is the username is blank.

Comment: It's not occurring in every audit. From my 80 reviews maybe 10 were an audit and maybe 5 of these were buggy. You are right with the grayed user though.

Comment: hmn, I just skipped through like 100 review audits in the first posts queue, and couldn't reproduce the described behavior... I'm done was always disabled

Comment: @m0sa It seems I am not the only one with that bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192721/229518

Comment: I've seen this just once before. And I failed the audit because I clicked "I'm Done"

Comment: ok, finally managed to reproduce.. fixing